# Python - About Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, sequence, fibonacci

I try to make a code that asks from the user to enter a positive number and then tells him/her if this number belongs to the Fibonacci sequence. The problem is that, when I run the code never stops runnning (or eventually I'll get an error). Here's my the code so far:

```
print("\nEnter any positive number, to see if it")
user = input("belongs to the Fibonacci sequence: ")

def fibo(user):
    if user in [0,1]:
        return user
    else:
        return fibo(user-1) + fibo(user-2)


while user.isdigit() == False:
    user = input("Input error. Please enter a positive number: ")
else:
    user = int(user)

if user == fibo(user):
    print("\nNumber",user,"belongs to the Fibonacci sequence.\n")
else:
    print("\nNumber",user,"doesn't belong to the Fibonacci sequence.\n")
```

Comment: Instead of trying to calculate the sequence recursively just calculate it forward until you reach a number which is greater or equal "user".

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I'm not completely sure how to do it...I mean, for sure, I'm going to erase the def fibo(user) function, but then where am I going to put the [0,1] and fibo(user-1) + fibo(user-2)...? Inside the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fibo(input):
    i = int(input)
    # set z to 1 if you want
    # False to be returned for 0
    x = 0; y = 1; z = 0
    while z < i:
        z = x + y; x = y; y = z
    return z == i
 
print(fibo(input("fibonacci?: ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibo(input):
    if int(input) == 0: return [0]
    x = 0; y = 1; z = 0; erg = []
    while True:
        z = x + z; x = y; y = z
        if y > int(input): break
        else: erg.append(y)
    if int(input) in erg: return True
    else: return False
 
print(fibo(input("fibonacci?: ")))
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply! I'm new to python so, can you please explain a bit more about x, y, z, erg=[], .append() and why we put fibo() inside the printf...? I'm a bit to confused to be honest :D!

Comment: If the code is not run interactively, the return value of a function won't be visible unless explicitly `print()`ed. I don't see the point of the list for your particular goal. Also there seems to be some typo. See my answer adapted from the above.

Comment: @TomYan is right, the list is not neccesary. i have it because used my script i made to give me all fibonacci numbers up to the inputed number as basis for this one. i didn't find a typo tho. still thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ahh, seems like it was a trick to include f0 and f1 in the list

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I rely appreciate it! And now I understood the code!